# Could Yuno do these things to win with both Yuki and her being alive?

Tags: mirai-nikki

Scenario 1: if Yuno from world 1 (Yuno 1) killed Yuno from world 2 (Yuno 2) to take her place, wouldn't that take her out of the game? With that, Yuki could win and Yuno 1 would still be alive in world 2 that is, though she might have had to wait for the game to start before doing this.

Scenario 2: if Yuno came to world 2 in the past, she could break Yuki's phone before the game preventing him from entering, in which case she could win with Yuki still being alive.

Scenario 3: if Yuno 1 kept Yuno 2 alive and just hid for awhile, she could let them play out the game for awhile. When it gets close to the end, Yuno 1 takes out Yuno 2 and Yuki wins in another way. Yuno 1 could still be alive, though that would make Yuki mad considering it wouldn't have been his Yuno 2.

Could Yuno do these things to win with both Yuki and her being alive?

Comment: Welcome to Anime.SE, The original post was a bit hard to understand without proper formatting that it got closed, next time please try your best in writing a clear question. I also tried to improve the post and also explicitly mentioned the implicit question (I guess it's about winning with Yuki and Yuno being alive?). Feel free to [edit] to improve or clarify the real question. Finally, consider taking a quick [tour] to understand how this site works. Thanks, and enjoy~

Answer (score 1):

According to the wiki:

> The game will officially end when only one diary owner is left alive

Meaning that even if Yuno1 came from a different world, since she still had a diary of her own she'd be counted as a Diary Owner and a participant of the Survival Game in World 2, or any world that she warped to.

Comment: But what about scenario 2?

Comment: Also the answer here https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4896/17758 contradicts this

Comment: contradict?? It says pretty much the same, the last diary owner wins. As long as Yuno1 still has her diary, she is still a participant, Minene stopped being a participant because she DESTROYED her own diary and died, but Deus saved her by giving her godly powers. And Scenario 2 would be possible but with a catch: Yuno becomes god, and as such, she gets stuck in that Cause and Effect something palace, though se might be able to interact with Yuki as an "imaginry friend."

Comment: paulnamida Yuno1's 'diary' in the 2nd universe is still the same diary as in the 1st universe? Or Yuno1 got a new diary in the 2nd universe? In this case, I guess Yuno1 just used Yuno2's diary but then did Yuno2 actually get a diary? What I remember is Yuno1 killed Yuno2 before the game started in the 2nd universe.